How do I create a funnel chart in ChartJS 3.8.x
I'm trying to create a funnel with this chart, but I can't find a way to make it work. I'm using VueCLI (vue 2).
After doing npm install chart.js chartjs-chart-funnel an error appears on console even without importing the chart: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'helpers')
What I tried and the errors I get:

Setting my chart type to funnel:

this.chartLeads2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("graphLead2"), {
    type: 'funnel',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'TOTAL LEADS',
            data: [this.data],
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'right',
                clamp: true,
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
})

Gives: Error: "funnel" is not a registered controller.

Registering it inline as a plugin:

import ChartFunnel from 'chartjs-chart-funnel';

this.chartLeads2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("graphLead2"), {
    type: 'funnel',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'TOTAL LEADS',
            data: [this.data],
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'right',
                clamp: true,
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels,ChartFunnel],
})

Gives: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Registering it as a plugin (with Chart.register(ChartFunnel)):

import ChartFunnel from 'chartjs-chart-funnel';
Chart.register(ChartFunnel)
this.chartLeads2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("graphLead2"), {
    type: 'funnel',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'TOTAL LEADS',
            data: [this.data],
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'right',
                clamp: true,
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels,ChartFunnel],
})

Gives: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what else I can try.

If you can, it might help to share a bit more code about how you are instantiating the Chart, even if none of the options are currently working. The only thing I can think of is that in the second point you are registering the plugin IN the options object, when the plugins should be outside the options.
https://www.sgratzl.com/chartjs-chart-funnel/examples/

@Skandog I added some code showing what I tried and fixed where I said I registered the plugins inside options, which I didn't. I remembered it wrong.

Thanks @MrJant that was really helpful, have provided an answer below. Hopefully this is useful

The GitHub for the package gives examples of how to initialise the plugin using ES Modules, which looks different to previous attempts - have you tried these approaches?
*"The ESM build of the library supports tree shaking thus having no side effects. As a consequence the chart.js library won't be automatically manipulated nor new controllers automatically registered. One has to manually import and register them.
Variant A:"*
import Chart, { LinearScale, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js';
import { FunnelController, TrapezoidElement } from 'chartjs-chart-funnel';

// register controller in chart.js and ensure the defaults are set
Chart.register(FunnelController, TrapezoidElement, LinearScale, CategoryScale);

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'), {
  type: 'funnel',
  data: {
    labels: ['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3', 'Step 4'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [0.7, 0.66, 0.61, 0.01],
      },
    ],
  },
});

Variant B:
import { FunnelChart } from 'chartjs-chart-funnel';

const chart = new FunnelChart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'), {
  data: {
    //...
  },
});

So for you data something like:
import { FunnelChart } from 'chartjs-chart-funnel';
    
    const chart = new FunnelChart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'), {
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          label: 'TOTAL LEADS',
          data: [this.data],
          fill: false,
          borderWidth: 1,
          datalabels: {
              anchor: 'end',
              align: 'right',
              clamp: true,
          }
      }]
    },
  });


This is it. I'm new to chartjs and didn't realise that I was importing a chart, not a plugin (even though I said it like a thousand times). Thank you

Ahh amazing, glad that worked  I've been using Chart.js a while now and I STILL find it crazy fiddly!
